# Accidentally Deleted My Main Screen

Tags: interface

I'm new to Blender
I used a split screen and instead of closing it, I closed the main one.
is there any way that I can bring back?

Comment: You'll need to add more details. Did you close blender, the 3d view? What did you split screen, etc.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know the vocabulary for Blender lol
The thing is I was working on a layout screen 
and then I added another screen to adjust the light
but instead of closing the new one (the one I was just adjusting the light on)
I accidentally closed the one I put all my work on.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I'm not quite sure what you mean, a photo would be helpful but if you accidentally exited 3D View you can select 3D View mode back from the mode select panel on the top left.

[image]

Comment: another note - if you ever just want the default screen layout again, you can just remove and re-add the "layout" tab from the workspaces bar and it will go back to the default.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know the vocabulary for Blender lol
The thing is I was working on a layout screen 
and then I added another screen to adjust the light
but instead of closing the new one (the one I was just adjusting the light on)
I accidentally closed the one I put all my work on.

 I tried selecting the 3D viewport again 
But the layout I was working on is still missing.